# Ajax implementation on table portion of jsp page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have to implement Ajax on a table,so that I can partially update the table after every ! hour.My JSP code is

```js
< head >
  < meta http - equiv = "Content-Type"
content = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" >
  < title > Insert title here < /title>
 
     </head >

  < body >
 
< jsp: useBean id = "bs" class = "beam_Status.BeamStatus_Bean" > < /jsp:useBean>
 
 < br >
  < h1 > Total Beamlines open are $ { bs.total_Beamopen()} < /h1>
 
<CENTER><H1>BEAMLINE STATUS</H1 > < /CENTER>
   <center>
<table  border = "1" cellpadding="1" width="750px" id="ajax"> 
 
     <tr> 
      <th><h1><b>BEAMLINES</b > < /h1></th >
  < th > < h1 > < b > STATUS < /b></h1 > < /th> 
        <th><h1>SYMBOLIC REPRESENTATION</h1 > < /th>
    </tr >

  < c: forEach
var = "country"
items = "${bs.beam_CurrentStatus()}" >
  < h3 > < b >
  < c: choose >
  < c: when test = "${country.value == 'IN OPERATION'}" >
  < tr >
  < td class = "green"
style = "text-transform: uppercase; "
width = "400px" > < center > < h1 > $ {
    country.key
  } < /h1></center > < /td> 
                <td class="green" style="text-transform: uppercase; "width="300px"><center><h1> ${country.value}</h1 > < /center> </td >
  < td width = "200px" > < center > < img src = "red.png"
align = "middle"
width = "100"
height = "110" / > < /center></td >
  < /tr> 
   </c: when >
  < c: otherwise >
  < tr >
  < td class = "red"
style = "text-transform: uppercase; "
width = "400px" > < center > < h1 > $ {
    country.key
  } < /h1></center > < /td> 
               <td class="red" style="text-transform: uppercase; "width="300px"><center> <h1>${country.value}</h1 > < /center> </td >
  < td width = "200px" > < center > < img src = "green.png"
align = "middle"
width = "100"
height = "110" / > < /center></td >
  < /tr> 
  </c: otherwise >
  < /c:choose>
</b > < /h3>
    </c: forEach >

  < /table>
 
</center >
```

RIGHT NOW ,WHOLE PAGE IS BEING REFRESHED, AS I HAVE USED.

> **<%
>    response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);
>   %>**

I'm very new to Ajax.Help me on implementing Ajax on it.

Comment: CAPS LOCK IS SCREAMING. Please fix your text so it is not all in caps.

Comment: Start by learning about Ajax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started Than you can make a call to the server, get the table rows and replace the content of the table. Using setTimeout to trigger the next fetch.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the link.But I can't understand that what is to be put in **httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){}** ,as in my application ,there is button on which when I click table will be updated.But I want it to update automatically.How to fix that?How to use setTimeout for that??

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea:

```
function reqListener () {
  var html = this.responseText;  //Server will return just the new html for the table
  document.getElementById("myTableWrapper").innerHTML = html;  //element around table you want to replace
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.onerror = function(){alert("error");};
oReq.open("get", "yourFileThatReturnsTheTable.php", true);
oReq.send();
```

Learn about the technologies you use.

Comment: Thanks  a lot.But still I have a silly question,as I have never implemented ajax in jsp.I want to ask that I have to create two jsp pages one for ajax and another for table and then have to pass the jsp page in oReq.open??Did I ahve to do something else in my ajax jsp page??